# forward a song using AUGraph in iPhone Mixer EQGraph Test

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing one player using the AUGraph (Taken example from iPhonemixerEQgraphtest). I have implemented go to next and previous songs. But since yesterday I have been working on forward option in player using the UISlider. Could any one please tell me how to implement the forward option .For better understanding I have included image.

Ex: If I slide the slider to 10 seconds then it has to play song from 10th seconds. Any ideas/suggestion could be very greatful

[image]

Comment: Even I am facing the same. If you have solved it. Can you please share your solution

Comment: Hi I have done with this. Please find my solution below

Answer (score 1):

Hi after a long research I have found the solution

In AUGraphController.mm I have change this code

```
// the render notification is used to keep track of the frame number position in the source audio
static OSStatus renderNotification(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    Simple_PlayerAppDelegate *appDel = (Simple_PlayerAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    SourceAudioBufferDataPtr userData = (SourceAudioBufferDataPtr)inRefCon;
    //NSLog(@"userdata out is %lu",(userData->frameNum/44100));

    appDel.secondsFromLocalSong = (userData->frameNum/44100);

    if (*ioActionFlags & kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender)
    {

        //printf("post render notification frameNum %ld inNumberFrames %ld\n", userData->frameNum, inNumberFrames);

        if(appDel.skipSecondsFromLocalSong>0)
        {
            userData->frameNum = (appDel.skipSecondsFromLocalSong*userData->maxNumFrames);
            appDel.skipSecondsFromLocalSong = 0;
        }
        else
            userData->frameNum += inNumberFrames;

        if (userData->frameNum >= userData->maxNumFrames) {
            //userData->frameNum = 0;
            SilenceData(ioData);
        }
    }

    return noErr;
}
```